# Block domains from being submitted and added to a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, .htaccess

I have a site that allows people to submit their domains to be added to a database. How can I block domains if certain domains contain a negative keyword (ex. porn, xxx, etc.)?

I know there is something like "*regular expressions*" that can do this but how do I create a .htaccess file that allows this? Or is there a better alternative like database filter?

I wish I had some example .htaccess code to show you but, I have no idea where to start when it comes to blocking keywords in a domain.

Comment: Why not just use `strstr()` to check if it has the negative word you wish to block, and simply not add it to the db, or return an error?

Comment: where would I add this? do you have an example.. (sorry a bit clueless on this whole issue)

Comment: What does `.htaccess` have to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is maintain a `blacklist`, which will contain a set of keywords which you do not want in the submitted domain names. Then you use any of php's string search functions to check if these words exist in the name.

These include [strpos](https://www.php.net/strpos), [strstr](https://www.php.net/strstr)

Of course regex are the more powerful way to go, but I am thinking that for now for your use case regular php string functions would suffice

Eg:

```
$blackList = array("porn","xxx","cuss_word");
$submittedDomain = "myDomainName";

foreach($blackList as $blackListWord)
{
   if (strpos($submittedDomain,$blackListWord) !== false)
   {
    die('Sorry, your domain name is not accepted');
   }
}

//...add to database here
```

Comment: THANK YOU! So far I've used the code you provided and I was able to block domains. good stuff!